# Information tables for operational amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier

Is there a place in the web (or elsewhere) where it is possible to find tables for operational amplifiers (and why not, other electronic components) like the one, for instance, in "The Art of Electronics", table 4.2.a.

I know big companies have their own catalogue, but it would be nice if this was done by electrical engineers for all the companies, possibly with some filtering system.

Comment: Who would pay for it to be kept up-to-date? Not the chip suppliers - they would hate their pride and joy op-amp being compared line-by-line with another supplier's best offering. Who would check that data was correct and would this "site" get sued for loss of revenue should a mistake be made describing a particular op-amp?

Comment: No one has to pay for it (see e.g. Wikipedia, or even sites that earn a lot of money with advertising). The site may warn that they are not responsible for the possible errors, and everything could be done by free contributors (like wikipedia).

Comment: sounds like you are well on your way to making a fortune if you have the time.

Comment: Yes, if only I had time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't any tables like that, and they would instantly become outdated. The best places to find op amps are:
1) From the manufacturers.

Linear\Analog All [Operational Amplifier Selection Table](http://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11070)

Texas instruments [Operational Amplifier Selection Table](http://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/op-amps/products.html)

Maxim Integrated [Operational Amplifier Selection Table](https://para.maximintegrated.com/en/results.mvp?fam=op_amp&tree=amps)

ST [Operational Amplifier Selection Table](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/search.html#q=op%20amp-t=products-page=1)

ect

From distributors (this one has most all the parts)

Digikey [Table of Op amps](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687)

Mouser [Table of Op amps](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Amplifier-ICs/_/N-4frvm/)

Yeah, it takes some additional time, but the tables are current and they also have pricing and stock information (why would you want an opamp if you couldn't order or buy it)

Comment: This is the closest to what I would like. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's not, as far as I know, a central maintained database of this information. It would simply be too time consuming to do, given the huge number of products. The best suggestion I can give would be to use a large parts distributor (Digikey, for example) and use the parametric search options for the whole of their opamp collection.

Comment: Note also that unless you have very special requirements, what would it help you to know that an opamp of specified properties exists, if you can't buy it with the rest of your parts? So, the large distributor approach works very well in practice: just use the ones that you'd buy the rest of stuff from. **Iff** you have multiple sources in your project anyway, compare across these.

Answer (score 3):

If you are buying things like op-amps you probably already know that there are only a limited number of companies that make them, particularly high performance ones.

You can go to parametric search at, say,  Digikey, which might help you identify emergent suppliers, but it's also useful to go to the websites of the usual suspects (Analog.com (also includes Linear.com now), Ti.com etc.) and use their parametric search engines. Digikey is pretty good, but they still miss things like listing Vos typical values rather than worst-case. In the end you have to go to information such as datasheets and app notes from the real manufacturer.

Anything less is 2nd hand information, and that's not good enough. Personally, I don't think I would use a list contributed by volunteers on, say, Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

As addition to @awjlogan there is also https://octopart.com/ which is also a search engine for electronical parts containing hundreds of distributors and thousands of manufacturers.

And finally there are of course paid options like https://www.siliconexpert.com/products/part-search which has billions of parts and can assist with building Bill Of Materials or finding cross reference parts.